# RSACryptoPad gives different results each time

Tags: cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to test my RSA implementation's correctness with the RSACryptoPAD example in here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10877/Public-Key-RSA-Encryption-in-C-NET

But it always creates different encryption results. Isn't RSA just a mod and power operation? But the program can decrypt all different encrypted texts correctly. My results are same with the http://nmichaels.org/rsa.py site. I think RSACryptoPAD is doing some other things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code uses [RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx). The line

```
  byte[] encryptedBytes = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt( tempBytes, true );
```

Tells it to encrypt using [OAEP padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding), which introduces randomness into the padding. The reason for doing this is so that encrypting the same plaintext will always yield different results (as you are seeing). This is a good thing, as it stops an information leak where an attacker sees you sent the same message multiple times.

There's a great historical example of why this is important. "[AF is short of water](http://www.nsa.gov/about/cryptologic_heritage/center_crypt_history/publications/battle_midway.shtml)"

Comment: Thanks. RSACryptoServiceProvider also reverses the bytes, i did that and now i can only decrypt the first byte?
'
    InvertibleRSAFunction privateKey;
    privateKey.Initialize(params.GetModulus(), params.GetPublicExponent(), params.GetPrivateExponent());
    
    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor decryptor(privateKey);
    StringSource(cipher, true,
                 new PK_DecryptorFilter(rng, decryptor,
                                        new StringSink(ugur)
                                        ) // PK_DecryptorFilter
                 ); // StringSource
'

Comment: Please create a new question about that ugur, you can paste your code there (I don't think reversing anything is necessary, but with enough info we should be able to help).